# Wrong bytes in xml

Tags: php, regex

I have an error message when open my xml page in browser

> error on line 62164 at column 28: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
>   Bytes: 0x0F 0xE2 0x80 0x93

How can i cut these bytes using regexp in php?

I'm trying this code

```
$invalid_characters = '/[0\x0F-0\xE2-0\x80-0\x93]/';

$body = preg_replace($invalid_characters, '', $body);
```

But it returns empty string in $`body`

Comment: It would be nice to see the erroneous line from XML. Why you use `0` and `-` in your regex?

Comment: I think I do not use the pattern in invalid_characters correctly

Comment: browser renders page up to the first error, so i cant show the erroneous line from XML

Comment: You could try this regex `'\x0F\xE2\x80\x93'` Although without real XML text it's hard to tell. Just open it in notepad or similar text editor.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot, '/\x0F\xE2\x80\x93/' works )))